# Column 'tempValue' does not belong to table

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I currently have an error while coding for my pie chart using ajax tookit in visual studio 2010. I have been stuck here for almost 2 hours and could not find any solution. I've tried searching in this forum and tried a few but still having the same problem can anyone please help?

```
private void BindChart()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["wkzdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    conn.Open();

    string query = "select count(case when tempValue < 24 then 1 end), count(case when tempValue between 24 and 30 then 1 end), count(case when tempValue > 30 then 1 end) FROM Datacentre";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    da.Fill(dt);

    string[] x = new string[] { "< 24 Degrees", "24 - 30 Degrees", "> 30 Degrees" };

    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
        {
            Category = x.ToString(),
            Data = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["tempValue"])
        }); //here is the error 'Column 'tempValue' does not belong to table'
    }
}
```

**Here is my table:**

[image: Database Table]

[image]

**How my pie chart looks like:**

[image]

**How i want it to look like:**

[image]

Comment: The error is quite specific - table `Datacentre` doesn't have a column named `tempValue`.   Post the schema of your table.

Comment: i dont believe i missed the column named tempValue in my table. i've edited my post so you can see for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bit of a disconnect in your code. First of all, your query is not naming the columns, so each column will have really funny looking name. Break on the dataset and expand it and you'll see what I mean. Start with the query:

```
string query = @"select count(case when tempValue < 24 then 1 end) as Cold,
                        count(case when tempValue between 24 and 30 then 1 end) as NotAsCold,
                        count(case when tempValue > 30 then 1 end) as Warmish
                 FROM Datacentre";
```

Then with these named columns, you have a value you can grab easily. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that pie chart, though. I'll leave that to you. You would change the line causing the error to something like:

```
Data = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["Cold"]);
```

**Update - The pie chart**

As I suspected, the resulting pie chart is not quite what you wanted. There are several issues here. First let's look at what *should* work:

```
for (var i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
    {
        Category = x[i],
        Data = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][i])
    });
}
```

Now let's explore what's different and why. We'll start with the foreach iterator. Given the query with 3 counts and no grouping, it's impossible to get more than one row of data, so iterating through the rows is meaningless.

So why did I switch it to a for loop? `x[]` contains 3 column headers and the query row has 3 columns, each in the same order. We want a slice of the pie reserved for each of those 3 columns. What better way to create those slices than an indexed for loop?

Note that the `Category` assignment is now referencing an item *in* the array, rather than the array itself. Since it is an array of strings we do not need the `ToString()` method anymore. The category you saw before is because `Array.ToString()` will return a string describing the array object - in this case `System.String[]`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. this helped. However, my pie chart came out weird. It did not went according to what i wanted it to be. I've edited my post. So would you please take a look again to see what is wrong? Thank you again in advance.

Comment: See the additional edit. Keep in mind with the edited pie chart section the column names are no longer important, still I consider it a good habit to name columns which would have nonsensical names if left alone.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT` is:

```
select count(case when tempValue < 24 then 1 end), count(case when tempValue between 24 and 30 then 1 end), count(case when tempValue > 30 then 1 end)
```

Which doesn't expose tempValue, so the code `dr["tempValue"]` can't read it.